# how to pass many values through the same variable in Django template

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a customized search form which has many inputs. Each input comes under specific category. This is about searching for a car. Hence, as a user, you can search for specific car condition, color, size and so on. each category(e.g condition) has many options that you can select from. You can select many conditions. The question is: How can I pass many values (e.g user can select car condition to be new, like new, good) through the same name (e.g name is condition)? also, is it possible to  pass all values from different category(e.g car condition, car color, car size) through only one name(e.g name condition)? the last question: what is the best practice to do that? I mean assign each value to different name or many values with the same category to the same name or assign all values from different categories to only one name, if this is possible how can many values be extracted in Django view function from the same name?  for only one value it can be done by:

```
condition  = request.GET.get('condition')
```

Here is portion of the form:

```
<form  method="GET" action="{% url 'some url' %}" data-action="" name="options_search" enctype="multipart/form-data" formnovalidate >

    <ul  class="att-list">
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_1" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="con_1" type="checkbox"
                 />
                new
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_2" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="con_2" type="checkbox"
                 />
                like new
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_3" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="con_3" type="checkbox"
                 />
                excellent
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_4" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="con_4" type="checkbox"
                 />
                good
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_5" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="con_5" type="checkbox"
                 />
                fair
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_6" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="con_6" type="checkbox"
                 />
                salvage
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul  class="att-list">
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_1" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="colr_1" type="checkbox"
                 />
                black
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_2" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="colr_2" type="checkbox"
                 />
                blue
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_3" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="colr_3" type="checkbox"
                 />
                red
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_4" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="colr_4" type="checkbox"
                 />
                white
            </label>
        </li>

    <ul  class="att-list">
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_1" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="size_1" type="checkbox"
                 />
                compact
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_2" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="size_2" type="checkbox"
                 />
                medium
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox ">
            <label>
                <input id="condition_3" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="size_3" type="checkbox"
                 />
                large
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form
```

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider making a model for each of these variables and saving to your database the possibilities of each variable, such as:

```
class Condition(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    variable = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And saving Condition entries to your database for 'New,' 'Used,' etc.
The same could be done for each type of variable which the user might select (i.e., model for Size, Color, etc.)

Then create a separate model for Car. This will be an instance of a Car the user might search for.

A separate model CarVariable will hold a foreign key to the car and a foreign key to each variable that might describe it. Note that while the model for CarVariable has fields for each type of variable, it should only reference one variable at a time. This will make sense later when filtering QuerySets.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CarVariable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    condition = models.ForeignKey(Condition, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

Note that there will likely be multiple CarVariable entries for each Car (i.e., one for size, one for color, etc.)

Now the view for the page which renders the form in question should include in the context a QuerySet of each variable for the form.

```
size = Size.objects.all()
```

Use this in the template to render the input field for each checkbox instead of hard coding each one.

```
<ul  class="att-list">
    {% for s in size %}
    <li class="checkbox ">
        <label>
            <input id="{{ s.id }}" name="condition" class="multi_checkbox" value="{{ s.id }}" type="checkbox"
             />
            {{ s.variable }}
        </label>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will not only provide you an easier way of rendering the form, but it will also make the submission of the form and retrieval of the appropriate car MUCH easier if you use AJAX instead of a Django Form.

When the user clicks the search button, have it call a Javascript function that takes the value of each 'condition,' 'size,' 'color,' etc class and add them to an array corresponding to their class.

```
$('.condition').each(function(i, obj) {
    condArray.push(obj.value);
});
```

When each array has been populated, make an AJAX call to a Django view which will essentially find all Car objects for which a CarVariable object with the id of the specified variable exists.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'django/view/url/',
    data: {
        condition: {'condArray': condArray},
        size: {'sizeArray': sizeArray},
        color: {'colorArray': colorArray},
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: grabcsrf('csrftoken')
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.result === 'OK') {
            console.log(response.cars);
        }
    }
});
```

Declare this function to get the CSRF token:

```
function grabcsrf(name) {
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURI(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue 
}
```

Now for the Django view.

```
from django.db.models import Q

def get_cars_by_variable(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.is_ajax():
        conditions = request.POST.getlist('condArray')
        sizes = request.POST.getlist('sizeArray')
        colors = request.POST.getlist('colorArray')

        var_hits = set()

        cond_hits = CarVariable.objects.filter(Q(condition__in=[con for con in conditions]))

        size_hits = CarVariable.objects.filter(Q(size__in=[size for size in sizes]))

        color_hits = CarVariable.objects.filter(Q(color__in=[color for color in colors]))

        for con in cond_hits:
            var_hits.add(con)

        for size in size_hits:
            var_hits.add(size)

        for color in color_hits:
            var_hits.add(color)

        return JsonResponse({
            'result': 'OK',
            'cars': list(var_hits)
             }, safe=False)
    return HttpResponse.status_code
return HttpResponse.status_code
```

From there, you should get to where you need to go. The response of the AJAX call will give you a list of the info you need. You could use those variables to render a new page with the cars you need or you could you Javascript to arrange the info on the page. Whatever you like.

I hope this adequately addressed your question. If not, I hope you at least got something useful from it. Good luck!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: your solution is so nice. However, There is one line if you can explain it more, because I think it does not fit my need.

Comment: var_hits = CarVariable.objects.filter(Q(condition__in=[con for con in conditions]) | Q(sizes__in=[size for size in sizes]) | Q(condition__in=[color for color in colors]))
you used  or (|) so if the user wants new  blue car only. this line will give him or her all new cars regardless of color and gives also all blue color cars regardless of the condition. and If I change it to AND (&) , there will be another problem which is if the user did not choose any condition (user needs blue cars for example regardless of the condition).

Comment: using AND without choosing  all parameters (for example car condition will always result in empty object (empty result) how can I handle that ???

Comment: Good point. I've edited my answer. Instead of a single QuerySet, make one for each variable and then loop through each, adding the result to an overall Set. Sets don't allow duplicates.